# PHP XML paginator with foreach

Tags: php, xml, pagination

I have code, which take information from xml file(in xml have example 5 blocks "groupRecord", can be more ). And i want show per page 4 blocks. I already wrote this part.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('GetLoyalty5001.xml');

$totaldata = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("groupRecord")->length;

$Pages = intval($_GET['page']);
if(!isset($Pages) || $Pages==0)
{
   $Pages=1;
}

$DataPerPage=4;
$numPages = ceil($totaldata/$DataPerPage);

$shopingdata = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("groupRecord");
foreach($shopingdata as $key=>$datashoping)
{
    if(??)
    {

?>
   <tr>
      <td width="156">STORE ADDRESS</td>
      <td width="222">STORE ADDRESS</td>
      <td width="266">STORE ADDRESS</td>
      <td width="161">STORE ADDRESS</td>
      <td width="156">STORE ADDRESS</td>
   </tr>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

What must I put in place of question mark in condition?

Comment: code physics behaves strangely

Comment: OK, I change my code and now page links work and show is right. Now only left condition, for show  4 blocks on per page

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have everything you need already, just use $numPages which yields the number of pages you have.

```
for ($a = 1; $a <= $numPages; $a++) {
    echo '<a href="?page=' . $a . '">' . $a . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Manuel, $numPages cant help, when i put $numPages, links show 9999. Maybe code some wrong

Comment: Why do you use `implode()`? Maybe thats whats breaking it, since it needs TWO parameters, but you only gave one. It doesnt make sence to implode the lengths of your dataset (Lets say Element 1 has length 2, Element 2 has length 10, that would result in 210)

Comment: Saying $dataArray has to be an array containing your data, while now its just a (imploded) string of numbers.

Comment: I change $dataArray  = $shopingdatalen; and now on pages links its work, but on first page show one block, not 4 blocks

Comment: I will take a closer look when I get home, thats a weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but the idea of how to calculate the number of items in the list seemed to go wrong.   All you needed to do was use the number of elements that you fetched using `$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("groupRecord")`.  I've reduced the code and this should do what your after...

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);

$shopingdata = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("groupRecord");
$perPage = 4;
$currentPage = intval($_GET['page']);

$numPages = ceil($shopingdata->length / $perPage);
if(!$currentPage || $currentPage > $numPages)
{
    $currentPage = 0;
}
$start = $currentPage * $perPage;
$end = ($currentPage * $perPage) + $perPage;

foreach($shopingdata as $key=>$datashoping)
{
    if($key >= $start && $key < $end)
    {
        ?>
    <tr>
       <td width="156">STORE ADDRESS</td>
       <td width="222">STORE ADDRESS</td>
       <td width="266">STORE ADDRESS</td>
       <td width="161">STORE ADDRESS</td>
       <td width="156">STORE ADDRESS</td>
    </tr>

<?php
   }
}

for($a=1;$a<=$numPages;$a++)
{
    echo '<a href="?page='.$a.'">'.$a.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Nigel, not work. When is page empty show 4 blocks, but when click on pages 1 or 2, blocks show wrong.